# Multiple jQuery mouseover mouseout

Tags: jquery, ajax, mouseover, mouseout

My jQuery code is  :

```
                num=15;                     
                        $('#share_button_'+num).mouseover(function(){       
                            $('#share_button_'+num).attr("src","img/share-hover.jpg");      
                        });                         
                        $('#share_button_'+num).mouseout(function(){        
                            $('#share_button_'+num).attr("src","img/share-button-en.jpg");      
                        });

                num=30;

                        $('#share_button_'+num).mouseover(function(){                               
                            $('#share_button_'+num).attr("src","img/share-hover.jpg");      
                        });                         
                        $('#share_button_'+num).mouseout(function(){        
                            $('#share_button_'+num).attr("src","img/share-button-en.jpg");      
                        });
```

My problem is that only the last one (can be the 15 or the 30) works. Is is written inside an Ajax success response :

```
        $.ajax({
        async: true,
        url: "myurl.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: "uid="+uid,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                //Written here
              }
```

Why is this happening?

```
var div=new Array();
div[0]=15;
div[1]=96;
div[2]=30;
var i=2;
$('#share_button_'+div[i]).mouseover(function(){
    $('#share_button_'+div[i]).attr("src","img/share-hover.jpg");
});
$('#share_button_'+div[i]).mouseout(function(){
    $('#share_button_'+div[i]).attr("src","img/share-button-en.jpg");
});
var j=1;
$('#share_button_'+div[j]).mouseover(function(){
    $('#share_button_'+div[j]).attr("src","img/share-hover.jpg");
});
$('#share_button_'+div[j]).mouseout(function(){
    $('#share_button_'+div[j]).attr("src","img/share-button-en.jpg");
})
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, I can see that the global var `num` is overwritten - 15 get's overwritten with 30 in each execution? Could you rephrase the question if I got you wrong, a bit hard to understand what you mean?

Comment: Yes, basicaly it happens into a for loop but I'm overwritting num just for testing

Comment: Be kind editing your post there are some mistakes in writing and like I said you should rephrase it, it's not clear what your problem is.

Comment: If you want them work together you must notice that your're using `#` and it means you're referring to the id - which is unique for the page, i.e. you can't have 2 IDs with the same name on HTML page? What is your html?